# How to find the ipaddress from a file and return the corresponding host name in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, file-io

Lets say, I have a file named `aaa.txt` in which the contents are stored in the following format:

```
# This is a comment
127.0.0.1     localhost
192.168.2.253     pyschools #pyschools server
100.0.0.4.9     amazon.com
.....
```

I need to write a Python function which accepts the string `ip_address` as argument and return the corresponding hostname searching for it from the file.

If the `ip_address` is not found in the file, it should return `unknown host`.

This is my working solution.

```
def gethostname(ip_address):
 w = open("aaa.txt")
  for line in w:
    line = line.rstrip()
    l = line.split('\t')
    k = line.split(" ")
    if ip_address == l[0] or ip_address == k[0]:
        return l[-1]
    else:
        continue
return "Unknown host"
```

> Example:
>
> if `ip_address = 127.0.0.1`, it should return `localhost`.
>   if `ip_address = 194.2.3`, it should return `unknown host`.

But, when I submit this code in pyschools.com[Topic 13: Question 10], it says `private test cases failed`.

I've been toiling hard with this problem for a long time now and I don't understand what I am missing.
[This is the link of that problem](http://www.pyschools.com/quiz/view_question/s13-q10). . You need to sign in using gmail to access it. Please do let me know if someone completes it

Comment: The python version used is 2.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code won't fail even if there is a line with an ip and no host name or a blank line.
And guys, all your strip and rstrip are useless since you use split !

```
def gethostname(ip_address):
    w = open("aaa.txt")
    for line in w:
        line = line.split()
        if line:
            ip = line[0]
            if ip_address == ip and len(line)>1:
                return line[1]
    return "Unknown host"
```

If you want some advice, you can use split only one time, and with no argument, since its default argument is ' \t\n' (and eventually more whitespace characters).
And `else: continue` is just useless at the end of a loop. Finally, you seem to have some problems in your indentation.

Comment: Sir, your solution says list index out of range for any input

Comment: In unix system, the '/etc/hosts' file contains the mappings of IP addresses to host names. Write a function that reads the /etc/hosts and return the hostname, given the ip address.
                                                                         
127.0.0.1     localhost
192.168.2.253     pyschools

This is the actual question

Comment: When I replace `"aaa.txt"` with `'/etc/hosts'`, it works on pyschools.

Answer (score 1):

Simply put them in a `dict` and use [`dict.get()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) like this:

```
def gethostname(ip_address):
    with open("aaa.txt") as f:
        data = [i.strip() for i in f if i.strip() != '']

    return dict([i.split() for i in data if len(i.split()) == 2]).get(ip_address, "Unknown host")
```

---

Demo:

```
def gethostname(ip_address):
    with open("aaa.txt") as f:
        data = [i.strip() for i in f if i.strip() != '']

    return dict([i.split() for i in data if len(i.split()) == 2]).get(ip_address, "Unknown host")

print gethostname('194.2.3')
print gethostname('192.168.2.253')
print gethostname('127.0.0.1')
```

Output:

```
Unknown host
pyschools
localhost
```

And to pass the quiz, here is another version from [here](https://github.com/xorpaul/utils/blob/master/gethostname.py):

```
def gethostname_split(ip_address):
    fh = open('/tmp/hosts', 'r')
    columns = {}
    for line in fh.readlines():
        if not line.startswith('#'):
            tokens = line.split()
            if len(tokens) > 1:
                columns[tokens[0]] = tokens[1]

    print columns
    try:
        return columns[ip_address]
    except KeyError:
        return 'Unknown host'
```

Comment: @pravn0993: Ah, okay.

Comment: @pravn0993: Well, is there some notes starts with `#` in hosts?

Comment: @pravn0993: Then we should pass it! Check my updated answer.

Comment: @pravn0993: Hmm...If the code is working...`"unknown host"` or `"Unknown host"`?

Comment: @pravn0993: Oh, by the way, I find this link: https://github.com/xorpaul/utils/blob/master/gethostname.py

Comment: OMG.. Thanks @Kevin Guan. The git hub code works. But i don't know what we missed and what type of test case i failed

Comment: @pravn0993: Well, also don't know. And I edited my answer. Please accept it if it's helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```
def gethostname(ip_address):
  w = open("aaa.txt")
  for line in w:
    k = line.split(" ")
    for iIdx, val in enumerate(k):
       k[iIdx] = val.strip()

    if ip_address in k:
        return k[-1].strip()

  return "Unknown host"
```

Comment: Your solution also has the same problem as mine. It says private test cases failed

Comment: Same error. just try it yourself and do let me know if you can solve it. (http://www.pyschools.com/quiz/view_question/s13-q10)

Comment: @pravn0993, I am sorry, but I don't have python installed at my side at present. That's why I can't try it out. Thanks for your patience by the way.

Comment: The link i sent you now is an online interpreter for python. just sign in using gmail and you will directly go to the problem